# A simple twist on a classic puzzle

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Given this sequence:

`0, 4, 84, 212, 1940, 358036, 14113428, 127377044`

What is the next item?

Hint:

> The sequence is not based on any mathematical operations

Hint:

> base

Comment: Not in the OEIS, impressive.

Comment: It's not difficult to come up with sequences that aren't in OEIS. What's impressive is coming up with ones that aren't there but deserve to be. (Which isn't _quite_ the same thing as being suitable for a puzzle here, of course.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sequence is

> The *classical* look-and-say sequence, but starting with a 0 and evaluated in base 4.

Proof:

> $$\begin{align}0_4 &= 0 \\10_4 &= 4 \\1110_4 &= 84 \\3110_4 &= 212 \\132110_4 &= 1940 \\1113122110_4 &= 358036 \\311311222110_4 &= 14113428 \\13211321322110_4 &= 127377044\end{align}$$

Trivia:

> Using base 4 is actually an interesting and meaningful idea because no digits can appear 4 times in a row in this sequence, so all "digits" are 3 or lower and thus valid in base 4.

Therefore, the next term in the sequence is

> **6006904289940**, because
>
> $$1113122113121113222110_4 = 6006904289940$$